# How to pan in visio like in a PDF viewer with the "hand" tool?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

In Visio 2016 we can pan the canvas by dragging middle mouse button: [image: pan with mouse middle button].

But I want to pan the canvas by dragging [like in a PDF viewer](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/adjusting-pdf-views.html) with [image]. How to do that?

Comment: **See**: [Zoom and pan in a diagram](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/zoom-and-pan-in-a-diagram-f9ee5535-7402-4e97-8b93-127e3ecbf027)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is another way that I have found:

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pan with the **right** mouse button.

Comment: Why is this not the default middle-mouse button? MS really irritates the user...

Comment: @CromeX because MS didn't write Visio, they bought it in 2000.

Comment: So do you think its a good idea?

Comment: No. What exists works well.

Comment: Each to their own I guess

Comment: This is the best Visio tip I've seen in years!

Answer (score 4):

Use the Pan & Zoom window.

Ribbon: **View** -> **Task Panes** -> **Pan & Zoom**

Comment: Thanks. But can I drag directly on the canvas instead of the Pan & Zoom window?

Comment: @zwcloud. No, you can't.

Comment: @zwcloud. A shape could cover the whole of the visible page area. Dragging is used to move shapes, so there would be no way to differentiate between panning and moving a shape.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think there is no way. MS could just add a "hand" tool. Or, like many other editors/viewers, when pressing space, drag the canvas to move it.